# How to generate jwt token in wordpress and using in url?

Tags: json

If url is present with parameter token request, check whether the user is logged in. If yes, generate and add the JWT token and redirect to the URL present in token request URL with the valid token. Should we use any hook function and is it safe to send jwt toke in url